# how to set a string in netlogo ? how to add charachters to a string in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

i was coding with netlogo 3.1.5 and i wrote the next code and it works (the S was already declared in globals [])

```
set S ""
ifelse (color = green)
[set S S + "0"][set S S + "1"]
```

the problem is when i wanted to work in netlogo 6.1.1 i copied and past the same code and it shows me an error which is the following:
+expected this input to be a number, but got a string instead

so can you please tell me how to set a string and add other strings in it ?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the quotation marks?

Comment: yes i tried but it didn't work. but actually i need them because it's a sting see the @JenB answer it's correcte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't using NetLogo back at v3 but I'm assuming the + is to concatenate. If so, the primitive you want is `word`. Here's a complete model for demonstration. Note that you need the bracket version if there are more than two inputs.

```
to testme
  let S "A"
  print S
  set S word S "B"
  print S
  set S (word S 1 2)
  print S
end
```